# SQL Server stored procedure error - subquery returns more than one value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to write a stored proc for populating income. the requirement is that I have two sections patient and spouse/other where patient income has to be populated under his section and spouse/other section should be under that section.

I have a problem when there are more then one member in spouse/other section! Below is my code.

error message says that----

> "@OtherMSN" "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not
>   permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or  when the
>   subquery is used as an expression."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
declare @app_id varchar(20), @msn int
declare @patient_msn varchar(5) 
set @patient_msn = (select msn from EXT_KSR_APP_MEMBERS (nolock) where app_id=@app_id and msn =@msn)

declare @OtherMSN varchar(3)
set @OtherMSN = (SELECT MSN FROM EXT_KSR_APP_MEMBERS (nolock) WHERE APP_ID = @app_id and msn <> @msn)

select distinct
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type = 'EJ' and msn = @patient_msn) as gross_salary_patient,
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type = 'CA' and msn = @patient_msn) as cash_income_patient,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in('ER','RT','S','SR') and msn = @patient_msn) as gross_ssn_income_patient,

(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='L' and msn = @patient_msn) as unemp_ben_patient,
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='J' and msn = @patient_msn) as st_disability_inc_patient,
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='A' and msn = @patient_msn)as a_c_support_patient,
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='M' and msn = @patient_msn) as pen_inc_patient,
(select gross_amount from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='RI' and msn = @patient_msn) as ren_prp_inc_patient,
--(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in('19','8','CR','FI','FS','G1','GA','IA','IC','IE','II','IK','IP','IU','LO','N','O','P','R','RI','T','TAN','TR') and msn = 1) as other_source_patient,

(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in('ER','RT','S','SR','EJ','CA','L','J','A','M','RI','19','8','CR','FI','FS','G1','GA','IA','IC','IE','II','IK','IP','IU','LO','N','O','P','R','RI','T','TAN','TR') and msn = @patient_msn) as total_mon_inc_patient

from app_member mem (nolock)
inner join app_income inc (nolock)
on mem.app_id = inc.app_id and mem.msn = inc.msn
where mem.app_id = @app_id and mem.msn = @patient_msn

select distinct
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type = 'EJ' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as gross_salary_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type = 'CA' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as cash_income_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in('ER','RT','S','SR') and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as gross_ssn_income_oth,

(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='L' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as unemp_ben_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='J' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as st_disability_inc_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='A' and msn in(@OtherMSN))as a_c_support_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='M' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as pen_inc_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type ='RI' and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as ren_prp_inc_oth,
-- (select sum(gross_amount) from app_income(nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in ('19','8','CR','FI','FS','G1','GA','IA','IC','IE','II','IK','IP','IU','LO','N','O','P','R','RI','T','TAN','TR') and msn = @OtherMSN) as other_source_oth,
(select sum(gross_amount) from app_income (nolock) where app_id = @app_id and income_type in('ER','RT','S','SR','EJ','CA','L','J','A','M','RI','19','8','CR','FI','FS','G1','GA','IA','IC','IE','II','IK','IP','IU','LO','N','O','P','R','RI','T','TAN','TR') and msn in (@OtherMSN)) as total_mon_inc_oth

from app_member mem (nolock)
inner join app_income inc (nolock)
on mem.app_id = inc.app_id and mem.msn = inc.msn
where mem.app_id = @app_id and mem.msn in (@OtherMSN)
```

Comment: What do you need help on? The reason for the error is simple and explained in the error.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your query returned more than one row:

`(SELECT MSN FROM EXT_KSR_APP_MEMBERS (nolock) WHERE APP_ID = @app_id and msn <> @msn)`

So there are multiple possible values for your variable `@OtherMSN`.  You need to fix your query to return a single row/column (scalar) value, in this case of type `varchar(3)`

Comment: I need to calculate the income for all the possible multiple values, not just a single value. the above proc works when the query returns a single row/column value.

Comment: If you need it to work with more than one value you need to refactor your query - and it really needs refactoring - it's horrible!!

Comment: Yes, refactor! You should sum "gross_amount" and by "income_type" for starters. Use case possibly for extracting the specific types... But any time you are using this many selects, you should refactor. It's a nightmare as far as efficiency goes.